# Extract DLL resource and save to disk

Tags: c++, file, resources, save

Can someone please give me a detailed explanation on how I can extract an external `.dll` resource from my executable and save it to a directory?

I'm working on Windows, using VS 2013.

Comment: You haven't supplied any details about the operating system, or executable file.

Comment: Added, sorry about that.

Comment: Please help, someone...